# Copy/paste value of preceding element using XLST

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="ims_prod">
<table_data name="wp_trp_dictionary_en_us_de_de">
<row>
<field name="id">1</field>
<field name="original">Random text 1</field>
<field name="translated"></field>
<field name="status">0</field>
<field name="block_type">0</field>
</row>
<row>
<field name="id">2</field>
<field name="original">Random text 2</field>
<field name="translated"></field>
<field name="status">0</field>
<field name="block_type">0</field>
</row>
</table_data>
</database>
</mysqldump>
```

I need to copy the value of every node that has "original" attribute and paste it into the following sibling (sibling that has "translated" attribute.

Expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mysqldump xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<database name="ims_prod">
<table_data name="wp_trp_dictionary_en_us_de_de">
<row>
<field name="id">1</field>
<field name="original">Random text 1</field>
<field name="translated">**Random text 1**</field>
<field name="status">0</field>
<field name="block_type">0</field>
</row>
<row>
<field name="id">2</field>
<field name="original">Random text 2</field>
<field name="translated">**Random text 2**</field>
<field name="status">0</field>
<field name="block_type">0</field>
</row>
</table_data>
</database>
</mysqldump>
```

I've tried the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:com="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//table_data/row/field[@name='original']/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="//table_data/row/field[@name='original']/following-sibling::field[@name='translated']"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it blanks out all nodes with "original" attributes instead.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the value of the `translated` field, so you need to make your template match that. And if the field is empty, then matching its text node will not work.

Try instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field[@name='translated']">
    <field name="translated">
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::field[@name='original']"/>
    </field>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. Note the use of relative path in `select="preceding-sibling::field[@name='original']"`. Your version would always select the first row's original.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these templates to get your desired outcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:com="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table_data/row/field[@name='translated']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('**',preceding-sibling::field[1]/text(),'**')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is as expected.